# EDB PostgreSQL restart service fails after trying to enable remove connections to database

Tags: postgresql, edb

I've installed a trial version of EDB PostgreSQL 11.3 on a RHEL 7.3 virtual machine.
I followed the installation steps and all went well until I tried to connect to the database from pgadmin and got this: `FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "10.2.191.84", user "system", database "postgres", SSL off`

So I set up enabling remote connection. Postgresql.conf had already had `listen_addresses = '*'` so I added

```
host    all             all              0.0.0.0/0                       md5
host    all             all              ::/0                            md5
```

And now I need to restart the database.

Installation instructions told me to run `systemctl restart edb-as-11` but that fails:

```
[root@EDBPostgre0 bin]# systemctl restart edb-as-11.service
Job for edb-as-11.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status edb-as-11.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
[root@EDBPostgre0 bin]# 
[root@EDBPostgre0 bin]# 
[root@EDBPostgre0 bin]# 
[root@EDBPostgre0 bin]# systemctl status edb-as-11.service
● edb-as-11.service - EDB Postgres Advanced Server 11
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/edb-as-11.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-04-28 17:33:22 IDT; 3s ago
  Process: 7142 ExecStartPre=/usr/edb/as11/bin/edb-as-11-check-db-dir ${PGDATA} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 28 17:33:22 meirav4EDBPostgre0 systemd[1]: Starting EDB Postgres Advanced Server 11...
Apr 28 17:33:22 meirav4EDBPostgre0 systemd[1]: edb-as-11.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Apr 28 17:33:22 meirav4EDBPostgre0 systemd[1]: Failed to start EDB Postgres Advanced Server 11.
Apr 28 17:33:22 meirav4EDBPostgre0 systemd[1]: Unit edb-as-11.service entered failed state.
Apr 28 17:33:22 meirav4EDBPostgre0 systemd[1]: edb-as-11.service failed.
[root@EDBPostgre0 bin]# journalctl -xe
Apr 28 17:33:22 EDBPostgre0 systemd[1]: Failed to start EDB Postgres Advanced Server 11.
-- Subject: Unit edb-as-11.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit edb-as-11.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
```

And what's strangest is that I can still connect to the database via psql. But I need to also connect to it remotely.

I tried to restart postgresql.service but there's no such thing on my machine. Using pg_ctl only told me off and pointed me to use systemctl.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The "real" error message can be found in the PostgreSQL server's log file.  But I don't know where to find that on your setup, I'd start by looking in the PGDATA folder, and in /var/log

Comment: @jjanes found this in the log:

```
2020-04-28 17:33:55 IDT LOG:  could not open file "postmaster.pid": No such file or directory
2020-04-28 17:33:55 IDT LOG:  performing immediate shutdown because data directory lock file is invalid
2020-04-28 17:33:55 IDT LOG:  received immediate shutdown request
```

ran find to look for postman.pid - there really isn't such a file. There's no syslog in my setup

Comment: Is there not a later log file with later messages?  Those messages do not look like what you would get from a failed start up attempt.  If you try to start again, do get more messages?

Comment: @jjanes you're right! And I tried to run "systemctly restaty edb-as-11" again now to see if any new log entry is written - the last log write was from when I opened this post two days ago.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I used two different installation guides on the EDB website because I followed the EDB installation guide to a regular postgreSQL guide via the EDB's links about one of the parameters. It caused a mess.
A second installation worked perfectly.